# Keras redefine input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I want to train a GRU and because I need `stateful=true` the batch-size has to be known beforehand.

Using the functional API I would have an Input as follows:

```
input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, None, features))
```

But when I evaluate the model I don't want to pass my test data in batches (batch_size = 1; predictions for one observation) with fixed timesteps. My
solution at the moment is to load the saved model and rebuild it with:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(None, num_input_dim))
```

To do that though I need a method that goes through every layer of the model and then
set the weights afterwards.

```
    input_1 = Input(shape=(None, num_input_dim))
    x1 = input_1
    weights = []
    for l in range(0, len(layers)):
        if isinstance(layers[l], keras.layers.GRU):
            x1 = GRU(layers[l].output_shape[-1], return_sequences=True)(x1)
            weights.append(layers[l].get_weights())
        elif isinstance(layers[l], keras.layers.Dense):
            x1 = Dense(layers[l].output_shape[-1], activation='tanh')(x1)
            weights.append(layers[l].get_weights())
        else:
            continue
```

(This is just an example and I find this solution very unelegant.)

There must be a better way to redefine the input shape. Can somebody help me out here
please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using a `stateful=True` model for evaluating, then you do need to redefine the model.

You can make a function to create the model taking the options as input:

```
def createModel(stateful, weights=None):

    #input
    if (stateful==True):
        batch = batch_size
    else:
        batch = None

    #You don't need fixed timesteps, even if the model is stateful
    input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, None, num_input_dim))

    #layer creation as you did with your first model
    ...
    out = LSTM(...., stateful=stateful)(someInput)
    ...

    model = Model(input_1,out)

    if weights is not None:
        model.set_weights(weights)

    return model
```

Work sequence:

```
#create the training model 

trainModel = createModel(True,None)

 #train
 ...

#create the other model
newModel = createModel(False,trainModel.get_weights())
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised. It's not necessary to know the number of timesteps. Anyways, your solution seems better than mine. Still I'm surprised, that it is necessary to rebuild the model instead of changing a single attribute.